# Filter values similar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want filter values ​​similar, I tried as following js code, but this code can not filter value `111` because this no `,`. my html code is as following (Some do, some do not this: `,`).

How can fix js code for filter all strings?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bNuRE/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="oo">111</div>
<div class="oo">111, 222, 333</div>
<div class="oo">444, 111</div>
<div class="oo">222, 333</div>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
<div class="ww">111</div>
<div class="ww">777</div>
<div class="ww">333</div>
<div class="ww">666</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var valeache = $('.oo').text().split(', ');
$.each(valeache, function (a, val) {
    $('.ww').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == val
    }).remove();
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Your demo seems to be working fine.

Comment: ok, `111` in `.oo` and `111` in `.ww` are similar, but don't work filter value for this. because this not have `, ` in `111` on `.oo`.

Comment: @TaylorGomez, is `333` in `.oo` also filtered?

Answer (score 1):

Your construction of `valeache` is wrong.

You need to iterate over each `.oo` element to correctly construct `valeache`.

```
var valeache = $('.oo').map(function(){
    return $(this).text().split(', ');
}).get();
$.each(valeache, function (a, val) {
    $('.ww').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text().trim() == val;
    }).remove();
});
```

Comment: Uhm, I still see something odd there, give me a minute

Comment: This creates an array of arrays.

Comment: @undefined, are you sure about that? Notice, the "odd" thing that I described is that there's no evidence that `333` shall be filtered or not I'm afraid. I will wait for OP's reply :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var valeache = null;

$('.oo').text(function(i, text) {
    valeache += text.replace(/\s/g,'') + ',';
})
valeache = $.unique( valeache .replace(/,$/,'').split(',') );

$.each(valeache, function (a, val) {
    $('.ww').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == val
    }).remove();
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xfSK4/3/**

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do.  Are you simply trying to remove the elements from the target list whose value match one of the (possibly comma-separated) values from any of the elements of the source list?  If so, I think you can do it more easily:

```
var vals = $.map($('.oo'), $.text).join(", ").split(", ");

$('.ww').filter(function () {
    return $.inArray($(this).text(), vals) > -1;
}).remove();
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/MVGLQ/1/**

That initial array contains duplicates, but that shouldn't be a problem.